# How do I format a patent application number for use in Inpass?

Tags: databases, india

[Inpass](http://ipindiaservices.gov.in/publicsearch/newpublicsearch/) is the search engine provided by IP India for Indian patents. It accepts the numbers of the patent applications in a specific format. Indian patent applications, as retrieved by search engines, often have a different format than that required from Inpass.

How do I format a patent application number for use in Inpass?

Comment: I couldn't understand the original question since it was a little brief, so I have proposed an edit which I think makes explicit what you were asking. But if I've got it wrong, please do feel free to roll it back.

Comment: I strongly disagree that the Patent Office of India assignes a patent application number in a different format than the one required by the search engine. Perhaps you refer to the format of the application numbers retrieved by subscription-paid databases?

Comment: I agree with you for both the things. Also, Patent applications which are cited in other patents doesn't use the same format as Indian patent office assigns.(same for Japanese and Korean)

Comment: @chempatent1981 Might I suggest you edit the question accordingly, to make it more accurate for posterity? I was just taking a stab, and clearly got it wrong.

Comment: @ASHUVERMA I edited the question, as suggested by Maca. Do you think it reflects your actual question?

Comment: @chempatent1981 its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Indian Patent office assignee patent application as IN YYYYAAAAA BC. YYYY means Year, AAAAA means Number and BC is the kind code. B can be of 2 type I and P. I respresent that patent file in indian patent office(Not claiming priority from PCT) and P represent that patent claims the priority from PCT. Further, C can be 1,2,3 and 4 which represent the city. 1 represent delhi, 2 represent mumbai, 3 represent kolkata and 4 represent chennai. if the patent application kind code is I then we have to open I1,I2,I3,I4 by DEL, MUM,KOL and CHE respectively. if the patent application kind code is P then we have to open  P1,P2,P3,P4 by DELNP, MUMNP,KOLNP and CHENP respectively

you can open patent application In the application number tab of the link, for ex:  IN200701142P2 . This number can be open as 1142/MUMNP/2007.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your answer that the number format *you need to enter at the search form* is the latter (1142/MUMNP/2007).

In India there are two numbers which are useful for identifying a patent (or application): the application number and the patent number. Until 31.12.2015 the numbering system for applications was NNNN/OFF/YYYY or NNNN/OFF*NP*/YYYY (NP stands for national phase and this means its a PCT entry). The office (OFF) of jurisdiction can be KOL, MUM, CHE, DEL, or KOLNP, MUMNP, CHENP, DELNP. This is the format required when using the INPASS. Databases may provide the application number in other formats, but one must convert it as shown above. Unfortunately, it is not rare to retrieve an application number which uses the NNNN and the YYYY but does not show the office. In this unfortunate case, there is no straightforward way of finding (and opening) the patent application at the INPASS. You must find it by searching with inventor name/applicant name and time span. From my experience those are the best fields to be used at the INPASS. The title may be substantially different than the one e.g. of a PCT application and key words may be an obstacle.

This numbering system is not in force anymore. With effect **from 01.01.2016** the new numbering system is yyyyJTnnnnnn, Y and N have the normal meaning as above, J=jurisdiction (can be any of 1-4) and T= application type (can be 1-9). There is no difficulty with the format used, just type the numbers as provided, without spaces. More details here: http://forums.epo.org/asian-patent-information-services/topic4662.html

The numbering system for patents is IN-NNNNNN-B and can be used either to check the fees (patent E-register) or at the patent search tab. The latter will provide you with the application number which is always required to open the file of the patent and check the documents of examination and formalities.

INPASS has changed its interface the past weeks. From my own experience, the new one does not function well yet, at least with Chrome, as I have not been able to find (and open) a specific patent application I have been monitoring for more than two years. What is more frustrating is that I can find and open it from another computer. Unfortunately, I have no explanation for this (yet).

As a general comment, the most reliable source (in a comparative level) for an FTO search is the Indian Patent Office itself. Few databases intergrate data from them. What's more, is that the Patent Office itself shows serious defects, some divisionals are not shown in searches (while they clearly met the conditions of the search), or the status displayed at the registry is not correct because there is a delay in updating it with respect to the actual status of the file. For what it's worth, a national entry in India from a PCT application is shown at the tab "national phase" of WIPO Patentscope with the correct format!

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is new format. what i mentioned is older format. Obviously we have to dealt with both type of number format. Do you have any idea for Korean, Mexican and Japanese patent. I knew about Japanese patent but have little knowledge for Korean and Mexican

Comment: Most of the time we get patent application number in IN YYYYAAAAA P1 before the 01.01.2016. that can be open in the search form as AAAAA/DELNP/YYYY

Comment: Can you tel me how to open IN201641015021A patent application in INPASS?

Comment: IN201641015021 should be opened by simply typing 201641015021. I know so, because I have opened a few Indian patent applications with the new numbering system (and I just doublechecked). However, the number you are giving me does nor provide a result. This either means that the number is wrong, or that the Indian Patent Office is malfunctioning (no offense, it happens quite often). For the numbering system of asian countries take a look at the EPO Asian Information  https://www.epo.org/searching-for-patents/helpful-resources/asian.html

Comment: You can try to open the patent application by using inventors' names.

Comment: EPO have provided the half way knowledge. Most of the time patent doesnt open the way its written in EPO.

Comment: Try this one: 201617018058

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58493/discussion-between-chempatent1981-and-ashu-verma).

Comment: I donot find any problem in new format. its the old format which creates prob. Further, half knowledge provided by EPO for Japanese and Korean Patents.

Answer (score 0):

Inpass has now become obsolete, the current search could be performed at [IPO](http://ipindiaservices.gov.in/publicsearch/)